# Document.querySelector() is not showing all elements

Tags: javascript, selenium, css-selectors, selectors-api, queryselector

I am a novice and trying to design both relative CSS selectors and JSPath to run my automation scripts.

While on the way, I could find the return statements are different between these two. Please check the below example. Could someone tell what changes I need to make in JSPath to keep the results same as relative CSS selectors.

**Result of Relative CSS selector.**

[image]

**Result of Relative JSPath.**

[image]

JS just returns first element while the css selectors returned multiple above. What changes do I need to make in JS to keep the results same.

Comment: try `querySelectorAll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Document.querySelector()

The *`Document`* method [*querySelector()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

> **Note**: The matching is done using depth-first pre-order traversal of
> the document's nodes starting with the first element in the document's
> markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of the number
> of child nodes.

Syntax:

```
element = document.querySelector(selectors);
```

---

### Document.querySelectorAll()

The *`Document`* method [*querySelectorAll()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

> **Note**: Although *`NodeList`* is not an *`Array`*, it is possible to
> iterate over it with *`forEach()`*. It can also be converted to a real
> *`Array`* using *`Array.from()`*. However, some older browsers have not implemented *`NodeList.forEach()`* nor *`Array.from()`*. This can
> be circumvented by using *`Array.prototype.forEach()`*.

Syntax:

```
elementList = parentNode.querySelectorAll(selectors);
```

---

### Using CssSelector

While using a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) or a [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) would return a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

---

### Conclusion

As discussed above, when you use *`querySelector()`* only the first matching element is returned. If your usecase is to return all the matching element, you need to use *`querySelectorAll()`* as:

```
document.querySelector("div[slot^='Learner']>div>div>span")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```js
document.querySelectorAll();
```