# Python Selenium can't find element by xpath within #shadow-root (open) using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, shadow-dom, nosuchelementexception, queryselector

I was browsing on this website: https://www.aldi-onlineshop.de/p/multimedia-pc-s23004-md34655-1014700/
I tried to click the button: "Alle bestätigen" with the following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.aldi-onlineshop.de/p/multimedia-pc-s23004-md34655-1014700/")
agree = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]//div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/button')
agree.click()
```

But that didn't work and it received the error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]//div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/button"}
(Session info: chrome=96.0.....)
```

How can I solve that problem, so it finds the element?

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>Alle bestätigen</kbd> button is within [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector)

[image: aldi]

---

### Solution

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on the desired element you need to use [querySelector()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194988/document-queryselector-is-not-showing-all-elements/70198069#70198069) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://www.aldi-onlineshop.de/p/multimedia-pc-s23004-md34655-1014700/")
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector('div#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')''').click()
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to extract info within a #shadow-root (open) using Selenium Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python/65055114#65055114)
- [How to get past a cookie agreement page using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734432/how-to-get-past-a-cookie-agreement-page-using-python-and-selenium/65735009#65735009)

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked for me. But why didn't my code work? Would it have worked with the ec visibility or something like that?

Comment: When there is a [#shadow-root (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) you have to use `querySelector()`. Even [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) alone won't be able to do.

Answer (score -1):

Your xpath is possibly incorrect, I recommend that you go down a level step by step, for example:

```
agree = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/)
```

If its correct:

```
agree = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/)
```

...

Another thing I noticed, is that double `"//"` wanted? `('/html/body/div[4]//div...)`