# How to SendKeys within textarea under shadow-root using Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, queryselector

I've used this Javascript based code but not working:

```cs
string scriptToSendAndPressEnter = @"
let textarea = document.querySelector('#root > div > div > div.chatroom-module__chatroom__eVUaK > div.chatroomEditor-module__editor_area__1UsgR > textarea-ex').shadowRoot.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.focus();
textarea.value = 'this text i want to send';
textarea.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { 'bubbles': true }));
var keyPressEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, keyCode: 13 });
textarea.dispatchEvent(keyPressEvent);
js.ExecuteScript(scriptToSendAndPressEnter);
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

The text is not send. I try to press enter by js but not working.

HTML Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is within a [***#shadow-root (open)***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73242476/7429447) so you need to use [*`Document.querySelector()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70198069/7429447) method and inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the [`ElementToBeClickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451578/7429447) you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('textarea-ex').shadowRoot.querySelector('textarea.input')"))).SendKeys("PoCoNoi");
```