# How to automate button click on cookie agreement under #shadow-root (open) using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I tried accessing the website to get data but the cookie consent pops up. I tried various ways to click "Accept All." The code always runs perfectly but the button is never clicked. I wonder what is wrong with my code.

This is what I tried

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.aplusa-online.com/vis/v1/en/exhprofiles/JP10FQtPTBydU4Ic9MvR7A?oid=19008&lang=2"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('usercentrics-roots').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")""")
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix the JavaScript query.

Use the below instead:

```
element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('div#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')""")
```

If you notice, the correct CSS selector to locate the `div` tag with `id="usercentrics-root"` would be `div#usercentrics-root`

Answer (score 0):

The element <kbd>Accept All</kbd> is within a [**#shadow-root (open)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65055114/7429447)

[image: shadowroot]

---

### Solution

To click on the element element <kbd>Accept All</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and using [***querySelector()***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70198069/7429447) method you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get("https://www.aplusa-online.com/vis/v1/en/exhprofiles/JP10FQtPTBydU4Ic9MvR7A?oid=19008&lang=2")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector("div#usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")''')))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Browser snapshot:

[image: aplusa-online]